# jquery slideDown() compatibility sith sticky js

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, sticky

On my site there is a drop-down menu sliding on hover. jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('ul.list li').hover(function () {
         clearTimeout($.data(this,'timer'));
         $('ul', this).stop(true,true).slideDown(400);
      }, function () {
        $.data(this,'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
          $('ul',this).stop(true,true).slideUp(400);
        }, this), 100));
      });
      // here is the place for sticky code
    });
```

It works pretty fine. But now I want to add sticky plugin. I put the following line to the place for sticky code:

```
$("#sticker").sticky();
```

And now submenus of the menu don't slide down, but just appear instantly. Why does it happen?

---

update: on JSFiddle it works just like it supposed to work.. haha..

I just noticed that in my site "sticker" is wrapped into "sticker-sticky-wrapper" twice, and on jsfiddle just once. But I don't think it matters..
So, any ideas?

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle example?

Comment: Add Jquery.js & Jquery.sticky.js both like <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>